# How to select 2 sub records using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table in MySQL with below Structure

```
user_mst
----------------
user_id
user_name
left_id        (fk to user_mst->user_id)
right_id       (fk to user_mst->user_id)
```

Now I want to select the records the way that suppose,

```
user_id = 1 
left_id = 2
right_id = 3
```

Now if I query records using User ID = 1, it should print user names that has ID 2 and 3.

**Sorry for the question updating, I would like to print the 2 separate records for left_id and right_id.**

So How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
u2.*
FROM users u1
JOIN users u2 ON u2.user_id IN (u1.left_id, u1.right_id)
WHERE u1.user_id  = 1
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Only does one join and handles the case of a record like 2, 2, 3 such that a left node can have only a right child or vice versa such that 2, 3, 2 will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
SELECT user_name, u1.user_name as LeftUser, u2.user_name as RightUser
FROM user_mst u0
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_mst u1 on u1.user_id = u0.left_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_mst u2 on u2.user_id = u0.right_id
WHERE user_id = ?
```